# Magento 2: Bulk update "This item has weight" flag for all products?

Tags: magento2, product-weight, bulk-products-update, bulk, bulk-actions

Im using shipping method "Weight vs. Destination". For this all items need to have a weight. I can bulk update the weight for all the products but i cant bulk update the flag "This item has weight".

I searched online and found some articles but none of them have a clear solution. Kindly help.

Comment: Maybe can we bulk update this in the database as i noticed that it is stored as "1" for product_has_weight variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out that there is no easier way to do this.
The only easier way this can be done is to replace directly in the database.

The other workaround for this is to change the values from **0** to **1** for all the instances of `product_has_weight` in the below to files.

```
.\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General.php
.\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Edit\WeightResolver.php
```

Finally go to Catalog->Products in Magento admin and bulk update(you dont have to change anything, just click update) all the product you want to change. Thanks it.